# PhantomJs Cloud - wait for Ajax

Tags: ajax, phantomjs

First of all, I wanna say I am a begginer. I dont know many things, so maybe this question will be really easy to answer.

I am using PhantomJs Cloud:
https://phantomjscloud.com/

And I need to get html of this page: https://www.pelikan.sk/akciove-letenky/

Tried many things, last one was:

```
https://phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:"https://www.pelikan.sk/akciove-letenky/",renderType:"html",requestSettings:{waitInterval:30000}}
```

But every time I get just loading page.

Thanks everybody for answers. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why don't you contact phantomjscloud.com tech support directly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be a support-case for phantomjscloud.